# Passing selected ID from component to another component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services

**Scenario:**

I have an api :

`https://................../api/branches`

As in the api `/branches` means the api as multiple `branches` with unique `ID` .Each `branch` will have it's own `contacts`.

Suppose i want see one particular **branch** contacts i will see like this in **POSTMAN**:

`https://................../api/branches/88fe-cc12-we33/contacts` **88fe-cc12-we33** is one  branch ID.

Now in my app.I am calling this particular `branch ID's` **contacts** in an component called **contacts** by hard coding that **branch  ID** like this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'asw-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
})
export class ContactsComponent  {
  public contacts: IContact[];

  constructor(public customersService: CustomersService) {} 

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.contacts = await this.customersService.getContactList('88fe-cc12-we33');<==========
    console.log(this.contacts);
  }


}
```

**customers.services.ts file**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IBranch, IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class CustomersService {
 private  baseUrl : string = 'https://................../api/';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

 public getBranchesInfo(branchId : string): Promise<IBranch> {
  const apiUrl: string = 'https://................../api/branches/';
  return this.http.get<IBranch>(apiUrl + branchId).toPromise();
 }

  public async getContactList(branchId: string): Promise<IContact[]> <=======
  {
    const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}branches/${'branchId'}/contacts`;
    return this.http.get<IContact[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
  }

}
```

Instead of hard coding and calling one **branch** contacts I want to call **contacts** based on which **branch** i selected, So i created an component called **branches** & i am displaying all the **branches** in the dropdown as in below pic:

[image]

**branch** component code:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Branch">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let branch of branches" [value]="branch.id">
  {{branch.name}}
</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';
import { IBranch } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'asw-branch',
  templateUrl: './branch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./branch.component.css']
})
export class BranchComponent implements OnInit {
 public branches: IBranch[];

  constructor(public customersService: CustomersService) {} 

 public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.branches = await this.customersService.getBranchesInfo('');
  }

}
```

As in the above code ,i am displaying all the `branches` in the `dropdown`,Now i want to send that selcted `branch id` to **contacts** component means to here:

```
public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.contacts = await this.customersService.getContactList('');<==========
  }
```

So the it will fetch the `contacts` based on the emitted `branch id`. I know that i can use **@Input** method in `parent` to `child` component communication but here both **(branches & contacts)** components  are separate components.There is no **parent-child** relation between them. How can i pass the `id` from `branches` component to `contacts` component?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, to share data between components that don't have the father-child relationship, you need to create a service.

In [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), you have a code example of how to do that.

Moreover, you can also [check this solution](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) that uses the BehaviorSubject of RxJS.

Answer (score -1):

using service you can subscribe to data in any component, and send data from any component in the application.

for example refer:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: should have attached relevant code specific to the question